# Why am I still seeing a wireframe in rendered - and all views?

Tags: 3d-view

In my scene, I have created another object. For some reason, regardless of the fact that I have disabled/adjusted the relevant checkboxes/drop-downs in the Viewport Display, I always see the wireframe for this object - but just vertices going in *one* way. In every single view mode.

Is there some additional view property I cannot find? Did I activate yet another thing without realizing it? And why is it just the horizontally aligned loops?
[image]

[Here is the source](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y3ZAkxMrIybCyQgxuVTbjpZ0c6AZo59t). When I'm working on using this in a scene, it's really visually annoying. This has happened before so I am eager to figure out what this actually *is*.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Just checked ur file. Just select all of ur mesh and hit merge by distance.

Comment: Oooh. Enter that as the answer so I can check it as correct. :) Thank you! Any thoughts as to why that happened? I'm not sure what triggers it, but I will keep it in mind in the future.

Comment: Added an answer with a possible 
explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In edit mode select all -> merge(m) -> By distance

Those edges are not part of that mesh. You can simply move them around by selecting those edges in edit mode
[image]

Comment: Oh wow, so I must have accidentally duplicated those without realizing. Thanks SO much.